# How to Check specific ID is exists in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

[Frontend design screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7B09.png)
I have a table named Team_members, columns are team_id, staffid and stafftype..I am fetching datas from job table. While fetching from job table

how to check if Team_id is not there in team member table (then return staff type empty field instead of showing No record found)?? or second senario if team_id is there in team_member table and check Leader(stafftype) is there belongs to that team_id.

**Team table looks like**

```
team_id team_name 
1        xyz
2        yux
3        iop

**Team Member table looks like**

team_id staff_id staff_type
1          13      Leader
1          14      Technician
2          11      Leader
// 1. ASSUME 3 TEAMID IS NOT THERE IN TEAM MEMBERS TABLE
// 2. Assume 3 teamid is there,and check 3 have Leader .Sometime 3 have other stafftype called "technican" 


**Staff table looks like**

staff_id staffname
13         abc
14         tyy
15         fdg

**Job table looks like**

job_id jobdate     starttime   team_id
1      12-09-2018               1
2      12-09-2019               3
3      12-09-2018               1
```

I need to fetch all the columns from the job table..In this am fetching staff name from stafftable. Before that i need to check team_id is exists in the Team member table.Sometime data wont be there

MODAL FUNCTION

```
public function list_job_by_asignedteam($getselectedteam){ //value 3

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->select('j.Start_time,
    LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), j.Start_time, 100), 7)) AS PeriodStarttime');
        $this->db->select('j.created_Dt as created_Dt_job, 
                            j.status as jobstatus,
                             mtos.created_Dt as created_Dt_mtos, 
                             mtos.type_of_services as type_of_services_name,
                             c.created_Dt as created_Dt_contract, 
                             aa.Contact_name as activity_contactname, 
                             aa.Location_name as Location_name_activityarea,
                             t.team_name as team_names,
                             aa.created_Dt as created_Dt_aa', false);
        $this->db->from('job j');
        $this->db->join('mt_type_of_services mtos', 'j.type_of_services_id = mtos.type_of_service_id');
        $this->db->join('contract c', 'j.Contract_id = c.Contract_id');
        $this->db->join('mt_business_type mbt', 'c.business_type_id = mbt.business_type_id');
        $this->db->join('activity_area aa', 'j.Activity_Area_id = aa.Activity_Area_id');
        $this->db->join('team t', 'j.team_id = t.team_id');

        //joining team_member table, staff table
        $this->db->join('team_members tm','t.team_id = tm.team_id');
        $this->db->join('staff s','tm.Staff_id = s.Staff_id');
        $this->db->where('tm.Staff_type', "Leader");


        $this->db->where("j.team_id",$getselectedteam); //value 3

        $this->db->order_by('Job_id', 'Desc');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return 'No Records Found';
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can team 3 have a job if they have no members? Or are you working with incomplete data?

Comment: @csabinho using team name only i have created a job..If suppose user created team name then can add a job..

Comment: so while fetching data from job i need to join table of team_members and to check team_id is exists or if exists means need to check Leader is there..Sometime other than Leader staff type will be there technician like that

Comment: team members will be in another table for that specific team name

Comment: @csabinho can u plz answer me

Comment: I don't really get it what you mean!

Comment: @csabinho actually i am fetching datas from job table. In job table teamid is there (3).

Comment: So i need to get the team leader name for the team_id 3..So i need to join the team_members table in this table only staff_type (Leader mentioned)  and staff_id. Staff name will be there in staff table

Comment: so when i select the the team id 3, this team_id is not there in Team_member table..So i need to show null value for the staff name.How to show it

Comment: @csabinho now from the above code showing No records found if team_id is not there in team_member table

Comment: Try a left outer join on `$this->db->join('team_members tm','t.team_id = tm.team_id');`. Just add `'left outer'` as third parameter!

Comment: $this->db->join('team_members tm','t.team_id = tm.team_id', 'left'); 
$this->db->join('staff s','tm.Staff_id = s.Staff_id', 'left');

Comment: Like this i have tried but not working

Comment: left outer not working still showing no records found

Comment: `left` != `left outer`

Comment: not working am getting {"job_list":"No Records Found"}

Comment: becoz am added two where clause right..  $this->db->where('tm.Staff_type', "Leader");
  
  $this->db->where("j.team_id",$getselectedteam);

Comment: @csabinho if first where clause,Leader is not there it will show no records found..Here is the problem

Comment: Oh, I just realized your `WHERE`-clause now. That's impossible!

Comment: Another question: does the team_member table even have a key?

Comment: Could you copy your DB dump to pastebin.com or somewhere like that and post the link here?

Comment: @csabinho yes team_member table have team_id

Comment: @csabinho plz checkthis db dumb https://pastebin.com/KanPY8CN

Comment: @csabinho on top i hav added screenshot of front end..it shows when i give teamname(passing team_id) and searching data from job table where team_id = 3..

Comment: @csabinho didi you got database dumb?any idea

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(Team_id) AS COUNTA FROM `Team Member` WHERE team_id=x;
```

If the COUNTA value is 0 then clearly the record you're searching for doesn't exist.

Comment: I guess he wants to do something like an `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @csabinho i have updated my modal function.In this code,if team_id is not there in team_members tables its showing NO RECORDs FOUND.instead of that i need to show staff name empty field..I am fetching datas from job table

Comment: ChrisFNZ Do have any idea ?